# Can a simple plot be used as a proof-without-words?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, experimental-mathematics

Can this simple plot be used as a proof-without-words?

**Edit** "No, it suggests but does not prove."

Plot of $2^{1 + n} = 1 + 3^n:$

[image]

Motivated by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1203909/28555), I reworked the non-loopback inequalities for Collatz and Waring into an equality:
$2^{1 + n} = 1 + 3^n$. It's easy to see the equality fails when $n\geq2$.

**Edit** $2^{1 + n} \neq 1 + 3^n$ is solvable for non-negative integer $n$, and is $n\geq2$.

Comment: Seems that the inequality can be shown without graphing, does it?

Comment: The chart certainly suggests (rather than proves) there is no equality above $n=2$ as the blue line is higher and seems to be growing faster. There are easy proofs of this.

Comment: Proof without words ... of what?

Comment: $2^{1+n}=1+3^n$ has two solutions in the real numbers: the derivatives of the two sides are equal only at $n=\dfrac{\log_e(2)+\log_e(\log_e(2))-\log_e(\log_e(3))}{\log_e(3)-\log_e(2)} \approx 0.5736$ so   there is at most one solution below and at most one solution above this.  So the only solutions are $n=0$ and $n=1$.

Comment: @Henry, could you combine your comments into an answer? I want to cite it, so I need a permalink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an easy inductive calculus-free proof for $n\geq 2$.  Start by showing that $3^{2}+1=10\gt2^{2+1}=8$.  Then:
$$\begin{align}
3^{n+1}+1&=3\cdot(3^n+1)-2\\
&\gt3\cdot2^{n+1}-2 &\text{ (by the induction hypothesis)}\\
&=(2\cdot2^{n+1})+(2^{n+1}-2)\\
&\gt 2\cdot 2^{n+1} &\text{ (since $2^{n+1}\gt 2)$}\\
&=2^{(n+1)+1}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

*Repeating comments as requested*

The chart certainly suggests (rather than proves) there is no equality above $n=2$ as the blue line is higher and seems to be growing faster. There are easy proofs of this.

$2^{1+n}=1+3^n$ has two solutions in the real numbers: the derivatives of the two sides are equal only at $n=\dfrac{\log_e(2)+\log_e(\log_e(2))-\log_e(\log_e(3))}{\log_e(3)-\log_e(2)} \approx 0.5736$ so there is at most one solution below and at most one solution above this. So the only solutions are $n=0$ and $n=1$.

Comment: Sorry, I switched accepted answers. I like both, but decided to go with the induction.